# Toolbar as self-managed ActionBar vs Toolbar as framework managed ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

Alright, I am trying to understand what I would lose if I use `Toolbar` as a self-managed `ActionBar` and not use [setSupportActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)).

AFAIK, all that `ActionBar` does is, provide placeholders for logo, navigation and menu items and also let `Fragments` add/customize the menu items.

The same functionality could be achieved using `Toolbar.setLogo()`, `Toolbar.setNavigationIcon()`, `Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()` and `Toolbar.inflateMenu()` apis. Of course, directing the menu handling logic to `Fragments` might be lost but I think that is not that big of deal if the `Activity` knows which `Fragment` is on top and changes the menu items accordingly.

I am trying to make sure :

- If I can achieve every `ActionBar` capability just by using `Toolbar` and `MenuItems` (and not using `setSupportActionBar()`).
- Is it ok to not have an exhaustive knowledge of `ActionBar` apis. Some of the `ActionBar` apis are very confusing. Using `setHomeAsUp` api to show hamburger icon, back icon etc., doesn't feel right. If someone starts learning android today, do they even need to understand the framework's `ActionBar` apis?

**Update** : In the article [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) under section `CoordinatorLayout and the app bar`, I learnt that the new paradigm *app bar* is a replacement for the action bar paradigm. I think action bar will soon be deprecated and we should get used to the new *app bar* paradigm which covers the new material design user experiences.

Comment: You're right about your update regarding Design Support Library, but as of today and AFAIK you still need `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in some cases: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31475986/603270

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use achieve similar capabilities of `ActionBar` in `Toolbar`.

Mainly the difference lies is `Toolbar` becomes part of `View` so we can much more fun playing with them to get [Scrolling Techniques](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html)

You can use `Toolbar` separately as `View` & perform `ActionBar` alike functionalities. For example, in one of my app I use 2 `Toolbar` one which is set to `setSupportActionBar()`  while other is just used for some other functionalities.

**Conclusion:** Well it depends upon your requirements if you want to use `Toolbar` as self or framework. None the less you can use it as both.

I hope this answers your question well.

Answer (score 0):

To me you are right.

From `AppCompatDelegate` source code, method `setSupportActionBar()`,

> When set to a non-null value the getSupportActionBar() method will return
>        an ActionBar object that can be used to control the given toolbar as if it were
>        a traditional window decor action bar. The toolbar's menu will be populated with the
>        Activity's options menu and the navigation button will be wired through the standard
>        android.R.id.home menu select action.

So these are most, if not all, the benefits you will have. As you said, it is easy to implement navigation and menu inflating through `Toolbar` APIs. However, I don't see what you would *gain* by not calling `setSupportActionBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

**YES** **YES** **YES**

using `setSupportToolBar()` is the same old `Actionbar` the only reason `ToolBar` is `ToolBar` is for versatility,same as `Fragment`s is to `View`s, all lies on how you implement stuff, and also the old `Actionbar` is kinda boring and much restricted as to `Toolbar`