# Home button not shown when using the design support library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-design-library

In my app, I'm displaying a Toolbar with the home button visible. In some screens this works as an up button, in others not.

That works fine.

Problem is that when importing the design support library, the home button is not shown in the toolbar.
This happens just by importing it, not a single line of code changed.

I'm importing it in Gradle with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Do I need to change something in code for the design library not to make the home button disappear? Is this another bug in the design library?

Note, I'm also using the support lib like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Also, this is how I inflate the `Toolbar`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- toolbar -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    [....]
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I set up the home button in one `Fragment`.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup         
          [....]
          final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)           
          view.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
          toolbar.setTitle(R.string.foo);
          toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.bar);
          [....]
    }
```

As said, these works perfectly fine until I just import the `design` lib in Gradle.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're using a custom Toolbar and now that you imported `design` it makes problems? Post your XML layout with a problematic Toolbar and some relevant code please.

Comment: You should also synchronize your major versions. If you are using `22.2.0` of `com.android.support:design`, you should be using `com.android.support.appcompat-v7:22.2.0`, or something else in the 22 major version.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes sorry. I'm using 22.2.0 in both. The 21+ was due to some tests I was making to investigate the problem that I mistakenly copy-pasted in the posted question. I've just edited the question.

Comment: @shkschneider the Toolbar I'm using is not custom. Is just a Toolbar I declare in the XML. I populate it using a standard XML menu, and I'm NOT using a custom layout. And yes, just by adding the line in Gradle that imports the design lib the home button disappears from the Toolbar in every fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personnaly get the `Toolbar` then set it as `ActionBar` and use the regular methods and it works for me.

Hope it helps you:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.foo);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as it, but please note that the problem was that I was missing   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)  . For some reason, if the design app is not imported, it will show the button even  without that line. I simply don't understand what's going on, but adding it definitively shows the icon.